# Monotouch- Access a native library's stderr

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, xamarin.ios, stderr

I am linking a third-party native library using the LinkWith attribute. This native library is outputting various logs in the stderr channel. I would like to access those logs because I need to report a bug in the said third-party library.

I tried redirecting the stderr with Console.SetError(Console.out) to have it in my console, but no dice. I also tried to output it in the Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal folder with the -keeptemp extra argument to have it on my disk, but this alternative also failed. Is there any other way to access the stderr of a linked native library?

Here is some code I tried:

```
var now = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));

string path = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string filePath = Path.Combine(path, now + ".txt");

TextWriter errStream = new StreamWriter(filePath);

// Redirect standard error stream to file.
Console.SetError(errStream);

Console.Error.WriteLine();
Console.Error.WriteLine("Application started at {0}.", now);
Console.Error.WriteLine();
```

Thank you for your time,
Paul

Comment: Both stdout and stderr should appear in the Xcode console when running in the debugger. Can you run your app in the Xcode debugger?

Comment: What do you mean? I use Monotouch and I run everything through MonoDevelop. There is a way to see the XCode output as well during I run my app in MonoDevelop?

Comment: If you meant the XCode Organizer console, I unfortunately didn't see the stderr print there when I was using the device.

Comment: You should be able to run the app from MonoDevelop (without the debugger), then attach the Xcode debugger to the running process, and have stdout and stderr show up in the debugger console.

Comment: Just open the iOS Device Log (in MonoDevelop's menu: View -> Pads -> iOS Device Log), and everything should show up there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rolf, I didn't know that existed! Nevertheless, iOS Device Logs only show me the logs of one of my native library, but not the other. For some reasons, the only way I can get the specific logs from my second native library is when I use the "emit debugging information" option in the compiler options. Anyways, I managed to get them, but I am clearly not understanding something here.